# Стилизовать активный чекбокс картинкой

Tags: css, css3, html5

Как реализовать чекбокс, чтобы вместо дефолтной галочки была моя картинка,
а дефолтная галочка была скрыта!

```css
/* The container */
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<label class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Допустим так

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
}

label > input {display: none;}

label > div {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: contain;
}

label input:checked ~ div {
  background-image: url('//i.imgur.com/r0hHvX0.png');
}
```

```html
<label for="check">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check">
  <div></div>
</label>
```

Comment: тогда нада чтобы серый блок оставался)

Comment: @svitalik1999gmailcom, обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо друг!!!)

Comment: @svitalik1999gmailcom, если ответ прям совсем помог, то можно отметить ещё и галочкой как "правильный"

Comment: а оно сразу не давало принять) сразу как бы не можно ...